# Can I still sell an AWS Reserved Instance if only paying for it monthly

Tags: amazon-web-services, reserved-instances

I'm looking at purchasing a reserved instance to access a GPU on AWS.  It's likely that a few month down the line i will need to migrate the workload elsewhere.

Can i still see the RI on the marketplace, even if i am only paying for it monthly with no upfront costs, to get out of the agreement?

Answer (score 1):

On the AWS RI Marketplaces you can't. They clearly state in the conditions that AWS must have received payment upfront.

"Reserved Instances can be sold after they have been active for at least 30 days and once AWS has received the upfront payment (if applicable)."

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/marketplace/

Comment: "(if applicable)".